# Proc Import from SPSS

Tags: sas

Relatively new to SAS and I'm using proc import on an SPSS (.sav) data file and it runs fine but I noticed that it brings in only the SPSS value labels rather than the numeric equivalent. As an example in the Gender column 1='male', 2='female' and in the SAS data set 'male' and 'female' show up rather than 1 or 2.

Any insight would be appreciated. Current code...

```
 proc import datafile = "C:\Data\workload_20130314.sav"
     out=library.workload_20130314
     dbms = sav
     replace;
 run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the underlying values there, they're probably just formatted.  Try opening the dataset and viewing the column properties of one of the columns you're looking at; it probably has a format that's like Q49F. or something that does that.  It still works with PROC MEANS or whatever as a numeric variable.

You can run, I think, something like

```
proc datasets;
modify my_dataset;
format _all_;
quit;
```

to remove the overlay.  You can also do that on a case by case basis.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The code will definitely give me a starting point.

Comment: But how do you make the overlay permanent?  In my case, after stacking data from several years, only the latest Q49F format is applied and 0=2012 for 2012 data, becomes 0=2014 (only the latest format is preserved after a vertical join).

Comment: The overlay is not meant to be permanent.  It's a format.  It disassociates the meaning from the code.  Normally, you would have a single codeframe across years (so you don't have the issue you describe).  If it does vary across years, you would need to do some work (often quite a bit of work) to either turn the formats into the actual values (ie, we'll need character variables instead of numeric now), or to modify the codes such that the codeframe is protected (say, YYYY00+value is the new value, and then adjust the formats).

Comment: I have a question like, when I import the value lables are gone and only the numbers are left.. what is the way to carry the value lables, that is the formats too?