# Import SPSS data into SAS without Labels and Values

Tags: import, sas, label, spss

As I am new to SAS I am having trouble to import spss data into sas using the "proc import" command. The code I was using:

```
proc import datafile = "C:\Users\spss.sav"
 out=work.test
 dbms = sav
 replace;
 run;
```

The main problem is that when imported to sas, the datatable variables have the values and not the coding. So for instance if the variable "Gender" is coded 1=male 2=female, each observation in sas has "female" or "male".

Now according to here:

[Proc Import from SPSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417951/proc-import-from-spss)

if the following code is added after the code above, then this problem ceases to exist:

```
proc datasets;
modify my_dataset;
format _all_;
quit;
```

What still remains is that the Variable names from spss, instead of having their name, when imported to sas they have the labels that are assigned in spss. Is there any command that can keep the Names of the variables in SAS, instead of the SPSS labels?

Comment: Note that your coding is actually there - if you have q1: 1=yes 2=no, and you say `if q1=1 then ...` it would work.  The value labels (formats) are solely cosmetic (and same with the variable labels).

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know that I could still use the name of the variable in the syntax, even though only the label of the variable appears. Thanks for that. However, in my data-set the number of variables exceeds 1000. So it is impossible to remember the actual name of all the variables, and since the labels are too long, it is not convenient to use them in the syntax. Therefore I need to "switch" from showing the labels, to showing the names, without deleting the labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that you are seeing column labels but that the underlying names still exist. You can modify your `datasets` procedure to remove the labels as well as the formats. Try this after your `proc import`:

```
proc datasets library = work;
    modify test;
    attrib _ALL_ label = " " format =;
run;
```

The `attrib` statement is applying a blank label and format to every variable.

Comment: Thanks SRSwift. Your code does the trick, and the names are appearing. However, with this way as you mention the labels and values are deleted. But in my dataset there are more than 1000 variables, and is important to keep both the name of the variable - so that in the editor i can refer to them with a short name -, and the label - in order to be able to correctly identify each variable with an explanatory description.

Therefore I am looking for a code to "switch" from showing the labels in SAS, to showing the names, instead of just deleting the labels.

Comment: Where are you trying to make this change, in a report or when you open the dataset? Unfortunately that's the default behaviour of SAS, to display the labels instead of names. When you open a dataset, you can switch to column names instead of labels, via View>Column Names.

Comment: If you want to see a reference for variable name, label pairs take a look at the output of `proc contents data = test; run;`. As Joe says labels are only cosmetic and you always refer to a variable by it's name in SAS code.

Comment: Reeza thanks a lot for your comment, that was what I was looking for initially.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I had yearly SPSS datasets for a survey and the same format, call it "Yearformat" would go 0=2011, 1=2012, ... for the 2011 data, but 0=2012, 1=2013, ..., for 2012 data, etc.  It seems like there should be a better solution, but what I did was .. 
SPSS -> save as SAS 9 for windows.. and click the option to output the formats to a sas dataset and then applied / modified the formats as necessary along the way .. mainly  data datacopy ; set data ; newyear = put(year,yearformat.) to preserve the proper years.

[image]

But the point is, SPSS will create a sas dataset without the formats and a script with the formats and code to apply/modify the dataset with those formats.  So you have control over the process.